# Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification Blank Duplicate system tray icon

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, systray

When loading my systray icon view xaml which uses Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification proxy, a duplicate systray icon renders with a blank icon alongside the correct functional systray icon.

Are there any known bugs with Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification that would cause this?

Answer (score 2):

yes sure there is, what actually happend is when you open your app there is icon created but when you close it your app don't remove the icon when he close so...
you just need to open the TaskbarNotification code and make the dispose method public and call it in the Application.Current.Exit event

```
Application.Current.Exit += new ExitEventHandler(Current_Exit);

void Current_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{            
     notifyIcon.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dispose() is already public however Dispose(bool disposing) is not. I should make that public?